# python xml parsing the functional way (map/reduce/filter) with existing libraries

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I work with massive XML files (osm) and often, for testing, I need to have a very faithful crop of that file - say - a small region couple of street blocks across. 
Say this is the file and  I want to filter out all data outside of a region - i.e.: points 666 and 777 and way 666777 plotted around them. 
(in practice there are billions of them)

```
<node id="107991" lat="51.5238819" lon="-0.1297082" version="5" timestamp="2016-03-24T02:10:47Z" changeset="38032277" uid="322039" user="MacLondon"/>
    <node id="4076120498" lat="51.5240418" lon="-0.1293314" version="1" timestamp="2016-03-24T02:10:46Z" changeset="38032277" uid="322039" user="MacLondon"/>
    <node id="4076120499" lat="51.5240767" lon="-0.1292776" version="1" timestamp="2016-03-24T02:10:46Z" changeset="38032277" uid="322039" user="MacLondon"/>
<node id="2453162758" lat="51.5241613" lon="-0.1290816" version="5" timestamp="2016-08-21T21:15:49Z" changeset="41598116" uid="17292" user="jpennycook"/>
<node id="2453162764" lat="51.5241841" lon="-0.129028" version="4" timestamp="2015-06-12T19:07:14Z" changeset="31929476" uid="1778799" user="SomeoneElse_Revert"/>
<node id="666" lat="60.5241613" lon="-0.1290816" version="5" timestamp="2016-08-21T21:15:49Z" changeset="41598116" uid="17292" user="jpennycook"/>
<node id="777" lat="60.5241841" lon="-0.129028" version="4" timestamp="2015-06-12T19:07:14Z" changeset="31929476" uid="1778799" user="SomeoneElse_Revert"/>

<way id="8173099" version="19" timestamp="2016-03-24T02:10:49Z" changeset="38032277" uid="322039" user="MacLondon">
    <nd ref="107991"/>
    <nd ref="4076120498"/>
    <nd ref="4076120499"/>
    <nd ref="2453162758"/>
    <nd ref="2453162764"/>
    <tag k="cycleway:right" v="opposite_lane"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="tertiary"/>
    <tag k="lit" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="maxspeed" v="20 mph"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Gordon Square"/>
    <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="sidewalk" v="right"/>
    <tag k="surface" v="asphalt"/>
</way>
<way id="666777" version="19" timestamp="2016-03-24T02:10:49Z" changeset="666777" uid="322039" user="MacLondon">
    <nd ref="666"/>
    <nd ref="777"/>
</way>
```

Regrettably, i have had my script suite already written in Python so i had to extended it with what i can only describe as an xml filter. I tried different ways of thinking about this problem and biased by scala i got this working (XMLPipe is something i wrote):

```
acceptedNodes = {}
def osmChildFilter(child):
    if child.name == "node":
        point = pyGeometry.GeoPoint(
            (float(child.attrs["lat"]), float(child.attrs["lon"]))
        )
        if region.contains(point):
            acceptedNodes[child.attrs["id"]] = True
            return True
    elif child.name == "way":
        return child.reduce(lambda cum, nd: cum or nd.attrs["ref"] in acceptedNodes, False)
    return False

XMLPipe(sys.argv[1]).map(
    lambda osm: osm.filter(osmChildFilter)
).write(sys.argv[2])
```

Because when you think of xml like of a nested container you can map on its root and then map again on the root's children and filter in/out some of the children's children, etc.

The trick of course is not to buffer (this is iterative parsing, like iterparse). Or buffer only small bits - which is necessary for the reduce bit to work - you have to run all the 
children of a way before you can decide to pass that way (with the children) down the function chain - and so you need to 'replay' them.
I think this may be semantically coolest yet method of iterative parsing of an xml/json file, but the code i landed with is messy and stupidly difficult to reason about - this is because it's a mere experiment that needs to be formalised. But before i go down that path - has anybody seen a lib that's already got it right? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Forgive me but your post sounds like you are thinking out loud and not clearly stating the problem, current results, and desired results.

Comment: The problem is that the known-to-be approaches for iterative xml (json is similar) parsing, namely ElementTree iterparse and xml.sax ContentHandler, make it remarkably difficult to write clean stateless code that communicates its purpose and the expected structure. So went to see if functional approaches can solve this and i arrived at very promising results. The question I therefore ask is whether any library that you folks came across attempted this already and landed with some measure of success.

Comment: Because if they did, i might switch to using this more mature approach. If they did not then maybe you will tell me that xml/json do not lend themselves to map/reduce semantics. But if you don't do neither of this, I might continue and attempt to mature the library, because i think it may be onto something.